# How to query for Tabsets related to a Lightning App in REST or SOAP API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, lightning-apps

I am trying to find a way to query the TabSet for a given Lightning App so I know which Tabs a user can access when that App is selected. This is useful when building a navigation menu in a custom UI/external connected app, for instance. I currently use the describeTabs SOAP call for this purpose, but cannot see any information about Lightning apps and tabs there.

I have read the documentation and tested the following SOAP API and REST API calls:

- SOAP: *describeAllTabs()* <-- gives all available Tab information but no related App information
- SOAP: *describeTabs()* <-- gives App information and related Tab information, but **omits Lightning apps/tabs** - this is pointed out in the documentation
- REST: *services/data/vxx.x/tabs* <-- gives all tab information but no App information
- REST: *services/data/vxx.x/appMenu/AppSwitcher* <-- gives available Lightning App information, including TabSet Id, but TabSet is not a queryable object

All of these give me some information, but none of them show me what we need: **The relationship between a Lightning App and its related Tabs**.

Is there a way to get this information?